# jquery get the ID of the great-great-great-great-grandparent

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have this line and I'm wondering if there's better way to do it.

```
var TheID = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
```

Note that the div for which I'm looking for the ID has class "MyClass", if that can help.

Thanks.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.MyClass').attr('id')` if there's no other `.MyClass` in between, which there shouldn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can also try [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for get attribute like this :

```
 $(this).closest('div.Myclass').attr('id');
```

or second way is

```
$(this).parents('div.Myclass').attr('id')
```

see here : http://jsfiddle.net/sKqBL/10/

Answer (score 3):

Get all the `.parents()`, and use `.eq()`...

```
$(this).parents().eq(5).attr('id');
```

---

...or the `:eq()` selector...

```
$(this).parents(':eq(5)').attr('id');
```

---

...or make a function...

```
function up(el, n) {
    while(n-- && (el = el.parentNode)) ;
    return el;
}
```

...and use it like this...

```
up(this, 5).id
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your definition of better?

```
//POJS, fastest
var TheID = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;

//jQuery, terse
var TheID = $(this).closest(".MyClass").prop("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var TheID = $('.MyClass').attr('id');
```

or

```
var TheID = $('#MyClass').attr('id');
```

is this what you mean? that will get the ID of .MyClass

Comment: The second one gets the id of an element using an id selector; it's redundant.

Comment: i know, but OP said ID has class MyClass so just included it incase thats what he wanted for what ever reson

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.parents`

```
var TheID = $(this).parents(".MyClass").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the id that you are trying to retrieve dynamically generated and so therefore you don't know what it is?

If so, consider assigning a unique CSS class name to the great-great-great grandparent.  Then you should be able to do something like this:

`$(".MyGreatGreatGreatGrandparentCssClass").attr("id");`

Of course, if you do this you may not need the great-great-great grandparent's id.